# Having trouble using the mvvm light Messenger class

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, messaging

I am trying to send a message from one viewmodel to the other. I am having trouble doing that. I followed this tutorial

[MVVMLight Messenger](https://www.mallibone.com/post/mvvmlight-messenger)

and everything seems to be okay until I get to this point.

```
    Messenger.Default.Register<VisibilityMessenger.MessageToSend>(this, ReceiveSampleMessage);

    private void ReceiveSampleMessage(VisibilityMessenger.MessageToSend message)
    {

    }
```

The first line Messenger.Default... I get the error that it doesnt exist.  I imported the messager namespace. I don't know what the problem could be. Nothing I found references this problem.

Answer (score 0):

MVVMLight Messenger requires .net framework 4.0 or higher. please check your project target framework and build your project again.

Comment: I am targeting Windows 10 Build 10240. I am using the framework for the MVVM classes. ViewModelBase, etc. they all work fine even everything else in that tutorial its just that one line.